# Read a single number from a text file and advance stream position in Julia

Tags: parsing, file-io, stream, julia

I understand that Julia has a complete set of low level tools for interfacing with binary files on one hand and some powerfull utilities such as `readdlm` to load text files containing rectangular data into `Array` structures on the other hand.

What I cannot discover in the standard library docs, however, is how to easily get input from less structured text files. In particular, what would be the Julia equivalent of the c++ idiom

```
some_input_stream >> a_variable_int_perhaps;
```

Given this is such a common usage scenario I am surprised something like this does not feature prominently in the standard library...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `readuntil` http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/io-network/#Base.readuntil

```
shell> cat test.txt
1 2 3 4

julia> i,j = open("test.txt") do f
            parse(Int, readuntil(f," ")), parse(Int, readuntil(f," "))
       end
(1,2)
```

EDIT: To address comments

To get the last integer in an irregularly formatted ascii file you could use `split` if you know the character preceding the integer (I've use a blank space here)

```
shell> cat test.txt
1.0, two five:$#!() + 4
last line 3

julia> i = open("test.txt") do f
           parse(Int, split(readline(f), " ")[end])
       end
4
```

As far as code length is concerned, the above examples are completely self contained and the file is opened and closed in an exception safe manner (i.e. wrapped in a try-finally block).  To do the same in C++ would be quite verbose.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the last number on a line (when it is not EOF)? Seems to get something even close to `operator>>` you need a lot of code.

Comment: See updated answer.  Also, since julia is dynamically typed it is very easy to wrap functionality like this is short (one-line) functions.